# Uncaught TypeError: _tslib_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, nuxt.js, nuxt-bridge

I am using [nuxt bridge](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/bridge) with [vue-layers](https://vuelayers.github.io/#/demo) plugin.

When I access the page in the browser, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _tslib_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is undefined
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, do you have a [repro]?

Comment: I get the same error, it doesn't seem to cause the page to not work though.